# npm install process stoped suddenly

Tags: node.js, npm

I typed [ npm install babel --save-dev] and it start downloading, but suddenly it stoped and It not progress any more[image: (I give a image )]

it's stop  and not downloading any more and also not show me any error . It's stoped
in this position.

I can't install any pacakages

Comment: Do CTRL+C (Windows) or CMD+C (Mac), then try again.

Comment: i tries from 2days

Comment: Then it's probably not supported anymore. Follow the comments and use `babel-cli` instead.

Comment: You may try running in verbose mode `npm install babel -ddd` and then inspect the logs

Comment: I try It's also not work it's log some text and then stoped. @capricorn

Comment: ooo, my problem solved . i log in my npm account by npm login . And after that all thing work very well. Thanks for helping me